Spacing between lines
I'm doing a cleveland dot plot in R. I have the months on x axis and species on y axis. The species are duplicated cause one is from phenology and the other is for seeds on birds feces, so I colored them differently. The graph looks good, but I'm trying to get a different spacing between different species, but I can't seem to get it done. I don't even know it that's possible. Can someone help me?

Here's my code:
 spp                    com   fim classe   cat
  <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 Casearia sylvestris      1     3      1     1
2 Pera glabrata            4     5      1     2
3 Trichilia pallida        1     2      1     3
4 Trichilia pallida       10    11      1     3
5 Casearia sylvestris.     1     5      2     1
6 Pera glabrata.           9    11      2     2
7 Pera glabrata.           1     5      2     2
8 Trichilia pallida.       9    11      2     3
9 Trichilia pallida.       1     2      2     3

duracao_pheno_birds <- ggplot(seeds_sync, aes(x = com, y = spp, xend = fim, yend = spp, 
group = spp, color = factor(classe))) +
geom_segment(size = 2) +
geom_point(aes(color = factor(classe)), size = 3.5) +  
geom_point(aes(x = fim, y = spp, color = factor(classe)), size = 3.5) +
labs(x = "Meses", y = "Espécies", color = "Categorias") +
scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "#6A0207", "2" = "#3B5708"),
                 labels = c("Sementes coletadas", "Fenologia")) +  
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
                 labels = c("A", "S", "O\n\n2022", "N", "D", "J", "F", 
"M\n\n 2023", "A", "M", "J", "J")) +
scale_y_discrete(labels = expression(italic("Trichilia pallida"), italic("Trichilia pallida"),
italic("Pera glabrata"), italic("Pera glabrata"),
                                   italic("Casearia sylvestris"), italic("Casearia sylvestris"))) +
theme_minimal() +
theme(legend.position = "top",
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), 
    text = element_text(size = 14))

I tried manually changing the spacing, but it didn't work cause I probably did it wrong.

Can you say more about what you mean specifically by "a different spacing between different species"? I think this will change depending on the size & resolution of your plot, and the size of your y axis text. A good explanation: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/

I want it to look like:
spp 1
|
spp 1
|
(empty line)
|
spp 2
|
...
I think maybe I should add lines with NA for the empty lines. Not sure. And if did, It probably would appear on the legend, and I don't know how to erase that.

you could use the aspect.ratio in theme() to control the spacing between the items on the y-axis. Note that the value is the ratio of height over width.
theme(
    aspect.ratio = 2/1
)


You've really only got three species since you've added a trailing "dot" after the species name for the second group (classe). If you don't do that, then you can use facetting, which allows you to adjust the spacing between panels (see panel.spacing()).
I believe you want something like this:

This plot can be achieved with the following code (note that I've removed the trailing dots after the species names in the second group).
ggplot(seeds_sync, aes(x = com, y=factor(classe), color = factor(classe))) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = fim), size = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 3.5) +  
  geom_point(aes(x = fim), size = 3.5) +
  facet_grid(spp~., switch="y") +
  labs(x = "Meses", y = "Espécies", color = "Categorias") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "#6A0207", "2" = "#3B5708"),
                     labels = c("Sementes coletadas", "Fenologia")) +  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, 
                     labels = c("A", "S", "O\n\n2022", "N", "D", "J", "F", 
                                "M\n\n 2023", "A", "M", "J", "J")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, face="italic"),
        panel.spacing = unit(1.5, "lines"))


I also removed your scale_y_discrete call because 1) it wasn't needed and 2) you had it reversed the incorrect way (R plots go from down to up, not up to down on the y-axis).

Data:
seeds_sync <- structure(list(spp = c("Casearia sylvestris", "Pera glabrata", 
"Trichilia pallida", "Trichilia pallida", "Casearia sylvestris", 
"Pera glabrata", "Pera glabrata", "Trichilia pallida", "Trichilia pallida"
), com = c(1, 4, 1, 10, 1, 9, 1, 9, 1), fim = c(3, 5, 2, 11, 
5, 11, 5, 11, 2), classe = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), cat = c(1, 
2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

